# Scroll div to bottom when rendered React

Tags: reactjs

I have a div of Messages in my chat application written in React. I want the div to be scrolled to the bottom when the user loads the page for the first time in order to see the latest messages. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `useLayoutEffect` hook to see when your div is rendered and use a refrence to your div element to scrollit to end

```
const Messages = () => {
    const divRef = useRef();

    ...
    
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        if (divRef.current) 
            divRef.current.scrollTop = divRef.current.scrollHeight;
    }, [divRef]);
    
    ...
    
    return (
        <div ref={divRef}>
        ...
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: What is the class component equivalent of this?

Comment: use ComponentDidMount() function and put the code inside useLayoutEffect in there and also replace useRef with React.createRef() inside constructor

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write useEffect hook either at the start when the component renders or when all the messages are fetched. Something like this

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
}, []);
or 
React.useEffect(() => {
   window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
}, [messages]);
```

Depends on how you're components are structured or how the views are managed. But this is the outline how you can trigger scrollTo when a user goes to your message screen.

Comment: How could I do this using class-based components?

Comment: use componentDidMount() for the first version and shouldComponentUpdate or maybe componentDidUpdate for second version

Comment: what should I do if the div im scrolling isn't the body?

Comment: Something like this probably var objDiv = document.getElementById("your_div");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;

Comment: but when should I call it? If i call it in componentDidMount, then the div is null

Comment: Can't comment for sure as you haven't shared the code, but writing it on div which you made scrollable inside which all messages are getting listed and maybe use componentDidUpdate.